# how to use build_vocab in gensim?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, gensim, doc2vec

1. Build_vocab extend my old vocabulary?

For example, my idea is when I use doc2vec(s) to train a model, it just builds the vocabulary from the datasets.  If I want to extend it, I need to use build_vocab()

2. Where should I use it?  Should I put it after "gensim.doc2vec()"?

For example:

```
sentences = gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedLineDocument(f_path)
dm_model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(sentences, dm=1, size=300, window=8, min_count=5, workers=4)
dm_model.build_vocab()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should follow working examples in gensim documentation/tutorials/notebooks or online tutorials to understand which steps are necessary and in what order.

In particular, *if* you provide your `sentences` corpus iterable on the `Doc2Vec()` initialization, it will *automatically* do both the vocabulary-discovery pass and all training – so you *don’t* then need to call either `build_vocab()` or `train()` yourself. And further, you would *never* call `build_vocab()` with no arguments. (No working example in docs or online will do what your code does – so don’t improvise new things until you’ve followed the examples and know why they do what they do.)

There is an optional `update` argument to `build_vocab()`, which purports to allow the expansion of a vocabulary from an earlier training session (in preparation for further training with the newer words). HOWEVER, it’s only been developed/tested with regard to `Word2Vec` models – there are reports it causes crashes when used with `Doc2Vec`. And even in `Word2Vec`, its overall effects and best-ways-to-use aren’t clear, across all training modes. So I don’t recommend its use except for experts who can read & interpret the source code, and many involved tradeoffs, on their own. If you receive a chunk of new texts, with new words, the best-grounded course of action, and easiest to evaluate/reason-about, is to re-train from scratch, using a combined corpus of all text examples.

Comment: Is there any advantage for calling build_vocab separately or during Doc2Vec initialization? Especially with regards to speed

Comment: If you supply a corpus iterable when you instantiate `Doc2Vec`, the initialization method will just call `build_vocab()` and then `train()` for you. (If you don't supply a corpus, it just skips that step & waits for you to call them.) So the total time required to instantiate/initialize/build-vocab/train is the same either way. Doing it explicitly just shows each step in your code more clearly, & gives you the option of either doing extra steps between each step, or varying the usual parameters. (Typically only more advanced tinkering requires that.)